# Why does function returns before it execution is completed?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have wrote following code;

```
var isValid = undefined;

alert(codeEditAddress());

function codeEditAddress() {
      test();
      return waitFor(function() { return isValid != undefined }, function(){return isValid});
}

function test(){
       setTimeout(function(){isValid = true;}, 1000);

}
function waitFor(fnReady, fnCallback) {
            var check = function () {
                if (fnReady()) {
                    fnCallback();
                }
                else {
                    setTimeout(check, 100);  // wait another 100ms, and try again
                }
            };
            check();
}
```

I see "undefined" in alert.

Expected result - to see "true" with delay 1 sec.

What do I wrong?

**P.S.**
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hg8h6622/3/)

Comment: The calls to `setTimeout()` return immediately. After the 100 milliseconds have elapsed, the system will call the "check" function.

Comment: Is it possible to refactor this code to achieve desired result?

Comment: You have to embrace the asynchronous nature of browser-based JavaScript architecture. You cannot make the thread of execution "wait" like you can in (for example) Java with `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: Can you show conrete code? your explanation is enough abstract

Comment: You have to perform the delayed actions *inside the callback function*. It doesn't make sense to expect a return value (note that your "waitFor" function doesn't even include a `return` statement).  [Here is a modified version of your jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/214190tj/)

Comment: It is wrong example. http://jsfiddle.net/214190tj/1/  **777** alert executes before **Finished!**

Comment: Right, because **calls to `setTimeout()` return immediately.**

Comment: But I need await)) like in java

Comment: You cannot have that in JavaScript.  The only solution is to put the code in the callback function(s).  There is no equivalent of `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: not friendly language(

Comment: @Pointy please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796705/how-to-check-adress-validity  it is a reason of this question